# Detection of physical or virtual machine in Windows

Tags: windows, vb6, virtual-machine

I wrote an application for Windows XP in Visual Basic 6.0. This application is running physical machine(PC) or virtual machine on many client side. But I need to change its license file in such a way so that I can the restrict the number of the devices.

Please also let me know how can I identify a unique physical or virtual machine in VB6.0.

Comment: Whether a "device" is physical or virtual shouldn't matter.  I suspect you really mean something else and are just "looking where the light seems good."  Rethink what you really want to do.

Comment: @Bob77 you can say that my application should run on fixed number of device whether it is running on physical or virtual device.

Comment: Why someone down vote my question?

Comment: Downvoter care to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware have a page which [describes how to detect their VMs](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009458). Other VMs may have other ways to allow detection.

And [this page](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?572678-RESOLVED-Getting-CPU-ID-and-BIOS-ID) contains code which should allow you to get the serial number of the BIOS, as VMWare describe.

Other VM software should have some method to detect the fact that your software is running in them, but they will differ from VMWare. So check their pages for details.

Unfortunately, I no longer have VB6 myself, so I cannot verify that this will work.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your answer.

Comment: the 'http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?572678-RESOLVED-Getting-CPU-ID-and-BIOS-ID' helps me to achieve my requirement.